# mysql flat design to php nested array

Tags: arrays, tree, nested, fancytree, flat

I have a simple mysql user table with a flat design like below. The table is ordered by Group5, ..., LibUser Ascending.

```
╔════════╤════════╤════════╤════════╤═══════════╗
║ Group5 │ Group4 │ Group3 │ Group2 │ LibUser   ║
╠════════╪════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════════╣
║ G5_1   │ G4_1   │ G3_1   │ G2_1   │ LibUser_1 ║
╟────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ G5_1   │ G4_1   │ G3_1   │ G2_1   │ LibUser_2 ║
╟────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ G5_1   │ G4_1   │ G3_1   │ G2_1   │ LibUser_3 ║
╟────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ G5_1   │ G4_1   │ G3_1   │ G2_2   │ LibUser_4 ║
╟────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ G5_1   │ G4_1   │ G3_2   │ G2_3   │ LibUser_5 ║
╟────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ ....   │ ....   │ ....   │ ....   │ ....      ║
╟────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ G5_n   │ G4_n   │ G3_n   │ G2_n   │ LibUser_n ║
╚════════╧════════╧════════╧════════╧═══════════╝
```

I want to transform this flat design to a hierarchical nested tree. The goal is to use fancytree.js to display it.

The final nested array with parents/children should almost look like this ("nbcpt" attribute is the number of users in the branch, don't pay attention to it). This is only an example, there is no exact link between the mysql table showed above and that nested array.

```
[
{"title": "All", "expanded": true, "folder": true, "nbcpt": 8, "children": [
    {"title": "G5_1", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 4, "children": [
        {"title": "G4_1", "nbcpt": 3, "folder": true, "children": [
            {"title": "G3_1", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 2, "children": [
                    {"title": "LibUser_1", "nbcpt": ""},
                    {"title": "LibUser_2", "nbcpt": ""}
,
                {"title": "G3_2", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 1, "children": [
                    {"title": "LibUser_3", "nbcpt": ""}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"title": "G4_2", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 1,"children": [
            {"title": "G3_3", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 1, "children": [
                {"title": "LibUser_4", "nbcpt": ""}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]},
        {"title": "G5_2", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 4, "children": [
        {"title": "G4_3", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 3, "children": [
            {"title": "G3_4", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 2, "children": [
                    {"title": "LibUser_5", "nbcpt": ""},
                    {"title": "LibUser_6", "nbcpt": ""},
                {"title": "G2_1", "nbcpt": 1, "children": [
                    {"title": "LibUser_7", "nbcpt": ""}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"title": "G3_5", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 1, "children": [
            {"title": "G2_2", "folder": true, "nbcpt": 1, "children": [
                {"title": "LibUser_8", "nbcpt": ""}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}  
]}
]
```

I read some examples when data is stored with a hierachical structure, but this is not the case here.

Any idea to transform this flat design to a tree ? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you could use the `postProcess` callback to adapt or convert the source data.
[The tutorial](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData) contains some examples.

While this is not the final code that exactly solves your problem, you may also get some ideas from this request:
https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/431